# Create core dump on purpose in C/C++?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I would like to create a core dump in my application on purpose, not only when it gets terminated.

I don't know if this is the right question, but is there any kernel function to call in my program like `dump_core("core.XXXX")`?
The goal I want to achieve is, to dump my core on some points in my application and later to debug this core dumps with gdb.

Comment: You want a dump but keep the program running?

Comment: You might get more expert responses if you ask this on the C tag, rather than C++.